# jQuery checkbox selected judgment

Tags: jquery, html

My goal is..
When the checkbox is selected, button is enabled.
When the checkbox is not selected, button is disabled.
**Defaults : checkbox is disabled**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="agree" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Go!</button>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" disabled value="">I agree.</label>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('input:checkbox[id="checkbox"]').is(':checked') == true) {
        $("#agree").attr("disabled",false);
    }
    else {
      $("#agree").attr("disabled",true);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are disabling input. Second - you are not listening for input change event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkbox').change(function() {
    $("#agree").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="agree" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Go!</button>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="">I agree.</label>
```

---

*Notes*

Changing attribute value does not changes attribute property. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)
Do not overkill selector. `input:checkbox[id="checkbox"]` is slower than simple `#checkbox`
Always try to optimize and minify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('input#checkbox').prop('checked') == true) {
        $("#agree").prop("disabled",false);
    }
    else {
      $("#agree").prop("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('input#checkbox').prop('checked') == 'checked') {
        $("#agree").prop("disabled",false);
    }
    else {
      $("#agree").prop("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox#checkbox').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'))
    $("#agree").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="agree" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Go!</button>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="">I agree.</label>
```

Use like this for single line

Comment: `$("#agree").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));` this is what i am referring mate no need for if condition